# Bridging home network with neighbor for automatic failover

Tags: networking, router, failover

So I can find a lot of information about failover, that's easy. But they all depend on us sharing the same network or making multiple connections to each others ISP. We have different ISP's, and both work from home. I'd like to be able to set up a single wireless connection that can server as an internet failover either direction. The "either direction" is what I'm struggling with. Setting up a single direction failover is simple enough.

I'm not so worried about the security implications. We can both set up VLAN's on our wireless routers. Or even add a dedicated wireless link if necessary. We are running different subnets. He's just running stock but I have no problem upgrading that if it's something I can do without Cisco grade hardware. I'm currently running DD-WRT. I've looked at Ubiquiti stuff, and it has great failover options if I have both ISP's at one location, but the only way I can figure out how to do what I want with that is to use 2 of them, and set up 2 separate wifi bridges so each routers secondary WAN port can be on the others LAN. I'd rather do it with a single link, because our range is already pushing it, but good enough for a failover, especially with an external AP on one side.

If this can scale out I'd offer it to other neighbors too. We have 3 different ISP options but none are great. There's just 12 houses in a little cluster out in a rural area. It would be awesome to be able to build a mesh between the houses for auto fail over and maybe even better burst speeds.

Thanks!

[Basic network idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Xwe.png)

Edit: Adding current plan: [This is the best I can come up with right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0TAH.png)
This requires two parallel wifi connections, with us each hosting an AP and a Client.

Like, it seems like I should be able to do this: [Router between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkaO6.png) and configure the primary routers to fail over to a secondary gateway inside the network, which happens to be a router that knows of the other gateway on the other network?  If I can do this, I can abstract away the wires with wifi, but I'm not sure what kind of hardware is even capable of doing this.

I totally accept that my hardware is not readily available to do this, so I'd take recommendations there as well.

Comment: I'm fine with both networks being isolated, we're not trying to share our private networks.  It's mainly the wireless link that I'd like to be able to go both directions so I don't have to establish two parallel wifi connections. Like, if this was all wired, would I have to have two different ethernet cables to accomplish this? I figured one of us would have to have an extra router between our network and the wifi bridge due to different subnets, but that's trivial.  I know DD-WRT *can* do failover with custom scripts, but I'd rather just buy a solution for that.


Added image to above.

Comment: I've started thinking about doing the exact same thing since my ISP dropped for another 90min in the middle of my workday today. You sound more savvy than I am on networking though =)

Did you find a solution that worked?